# How to make Shadow effect with no direction in Windows wpf xaml?

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

My xaml code is as below, its UI effect is as below picture shown.
As you can see, I set Direction=90, so the picture shows that the shadow focuses more on 90 degree direction. But I hope to make the shadow effect equal in any direction.

Any advise?

```
<Border CornerRadius="30" Width="254" Height="50" Background="White">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect
            ShadowDepth="2"
            Direction="90"
            Color="Black"
            Opacity="0.2"
            BlurRadius="18"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```

[image]

Comment: `DropShadowEffect.ShadowDepth="0"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set the `ShadowDepth=0`. After this you can then remove the angle attribute and get the desired result:

```
                <Border Margin="5" CornerRadius="30" Width="254" Height="50" Background="White">
                    <Border.Effect>
                        <DropShadowEffect
                            ShadowDepth="0"
                            Color="Black"
                            Opacity="0.5"
                            BlurRadius="18"/>
                    </Border.Effect>
                </Border>
```

[image]

Answer (score -1):

make direction 45

```
<Border CornerRadius="30" Width="254" Height="50" Background="White">
    <Border.Effect>
        <DropShadowEffect
            ShadowDepth="2"
            Direction="45"
            Color="Black"
            Opacity="0.2"
            BlurRadius="18"/>
    </Border.Effect>
</Border>
```